# Associating ROMs and RAMs

Tags: digital-logic, memory, ram, rom

Can someone explain to me how to associate  smaller RAMs and ROMs to make a bigger one?

For example: How do I make a 1024x8 RAM with 512x4 RAM?

Comment: what kind of RAMs and ROMs are they? ... how are they connected to the CPU?

Answer (score 5):

- Counting the number of memory cells in both RAMs, four 512x4 RAMs are required to build one 1024x8 RAM.
- 9 address lines A0-A8 are required to address one 512x4 RAM. 
  Cascade the data lines of two such 512x4 RAMs to obtain one 512x8 RAM.
- Now cascade two such 512x8 RAMs to obtain one 1024x8 RAM. 10 address lines are needed to address one 1024x8 RAM. So you can set the 10th address line A9 as enable (using a not gate or simple 1X2 decoder) to select one of the two 512x8 RAMs.

Something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Combining two chips to get a wider data with the same address space is easy. This is how you would do for two 2x2 ROMs to combine them into 2x4 ROM. Just connect the control and address signals in parallel and have twice more data bits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTUqCo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Combining chips into a larger address space is a bit more tricky. You need extra address lines which will be the MSB of the address and will *select* the chip to be accessed using a decoder (or some other logic):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVYefT.png)</sup>

Here you combine four 4x2 ROMs into 16x2 ROMs.